# How is a VHDL variable synthesized by synthesis tools

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, rtl

I know two ways in which a VHDL variable is synthesized by synthesis tool:

- Variable synthesized as Combinational logic
- Variable synthesized as a Latch unintentionally (when an uninitialized variable is assigned to a signal or another variable)

What are the other ways in which a VHDL variable can be synthesized ? (Example: can it be interpreted as a FF ? )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would distinguish three possibilities:

1. A VHDL variable has no hardware representation at all. Assume the following example

   ```
   signal a,b,c : integer;  
   ...  
   process ( clk ) is  
   variable var : integer := 0;  
   begin  
   if ( rising_edge(clk) ) then  
   var := a + b;  
   c <= var;  
   end if;  
   end process;
   ```

   The variable `var` is not really synthesized as combinatorial logic at all (assuming this is what was meant in the question). It's rather the right hand side of the assignment `a + b` that is synthesized into hardware. Strictly speaking a variable never is synthesized into combinatorial logic.
2. A variable merely holds an intermediate result, which is either evaluated in the same clock cycle -> no hardware synthesized ( this is 1) again ), or is evaluated in the following clock cycle -> a flipflop is synthezised.
3. One of those dreaded latches is inferred in such cases where conditional branches exist in which the variable is assigned neither a new value (depending on some signals) nor a default value. Usually this case happens unintended :-)

Comment: The "dreaded latch" can only happen outside of a clocked process though and most people (in my experience) these days are not using non-clocked processes.  So the latch dread is not an issue anymore (IMHO) - it stems from the olden days when you *had* to write your combinatorial logic in a separate process to your flip flops

Answer (score 6):

If you use the value in a variable before you store it, you get the value that was stored last time the process stored it (in a clocked process, the value from a previous clock cycle). That is synthesised as a register or FF.

Of course, in the first clock cycle you get garbage, unless you initialised the variable in a reset clause.